# Is it possible to create a proper flowchart in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I like draw.io’s interface and was hoping to create some proper Data Flow Diagrams (flowcharts) with this tool. Unfortunately, after playing a few minutes with the shapes available within the *Flowchart* section, I am concern that it is impossible in draw.io.

1. Shapes don’t have names as in case of UML shapes—is there an option to display shapes’ names in flowchart section?
2. I cannot find the shape for Interface (box)—is it missing?
3. It seems that although there is a shape for a process with sub-processes, it is not possible to actually hide a sub-process under a process shape nor create lower level diagrams that are linked with the 0 level diagram. Or is it possible but I am missing something?

Comment: 1. No, but it's on our todo to switch them back on. 2. Could you link to an image of this shape. I thought the interface is the 4th from left on the top row of the UML section. 3. That's not possible currently.

Comment: 1. Great, thanks. 2. This is how flowchart shapes section looks like in my Opera browser: http://grab.by/jici currently I am ussing box element from 'General' shapes section. 3. It would be a great feature ie. a possibility to save several diagram files and link them under selected diagram element (or even better include them under an element ;-) ).